# Fastest way to deserialize Int vector in scala

Tags: scala

I have a Vector which I use as a look-up table based on index of the element. It's really huge (30+ million elements). I want to store it on file system and every time I start my application, read it into some object.
I currently see three options here:

1. just write a file full of ints
2. use binary format
3. serialize object with Vector in it

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a file full of ints, then use a wrapper around a memory-mapped file to read it.

```
class MMappedIntVector (mmap: java.nio.MappedByteBuffer) {
  def getInt (idx: Int): Int = mmap.getInt (idx * 4)
}
object MMappedIntVector {
  def load (path: String): MMappedIntVector = {
    // mmap here
  }
}
```

The downside, of course, is that the file format ends up being locked to the endianness of your CPU.

Comment: This may ease IO bottleneck, but what about deserialization costs? Please, share actual measurements if you have one.

Comment: There is no deserialization costs, it's a memory read. Sun/Oracle JIT optimizes even the method call away (the `MappedByteBuffer.getInt` one), last time I've checked.

Comment: I was talking about re-constructing of vector

Comment: What re-constructing? There is no reconstructing, only the memory mapping.